# What are the cultural and religious differences between Hindus in India and Bali?

Tags: worship, culture

Indonesia is the country with largest Muslim population but majority of people in Bali islands are Hindus. I want to know whether there are any cultural and religious differences or similarities between Bali and Indian Hinduism? Do Bali Hindus worship Trimurti i.e. Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva?

Answer (score 2):

**Indonesian/Balinese Culture**

Yes Balinese Hinduism is similar to Indian Hinduism both [revere same set of Scriptures](https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/vedas-in-bali-islands-catur-veda-sira/) with Supremacy of Vedas. The supreme Bramhan is known by the name [Achintya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acintya), you can read more about [Hindu Rulers of Bali](https://tamilandvedas.com/2015/01/29/hindu-kings-of-indonesia/).

**Temples Dedicated to Trimurti**

**Shriman Naryana :**

- Shri Balaji Venkateshwara Kovil, Jln.Bunga Wijaya Kesuma/Pasar
  IV,Padang Bulan, Medan
- [Parambanan Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prambanan)

**Shiva** :

- Sri Siva Temple, Pluit, North Jakarta
- [Parambanan Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prambanan)

**Bramha** :

- [Prambanan Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prambanan)

So its clear that Bali people worship Trimuriti.

Comment: The main difference is there is no scheduled caste(Untouchables) in Bali Hinduism. Interesting thing is that island was never ruled by Buddhist and Islamist.

Comment: @Ajay Do you have any proof for that?

Comment: just search online and learn about their culture.

Answer (score 1):

During the time of Cholas, Hinduism spread across Indonesia. 
Hence they have connection to Hindus here as their culture can be traced to India. 
Example : Their national epic is Ramayana(tale is a bit different compared to Indian Ramayana).
Yes they do worship trimurti's

Comment: It was predominantly Hindu.